# Как из одной колонки число от 1-36 автоматом проставить следующие 2 колонки с другими данными, в зависимости от выбранного числа 1-36

Tags: javascript, таблицы

Подскажите, как сделать и в чём лучше реализовать, из одной колонки, цифры от 1-36 , на основании от того какая цифра стоит, автоматический в следующих 2 колонках ставило значения.
У каждого числа из колонки С, есть известные постоянные значения,
Например колонка C5=20, D5=2, E5=4. При изменении C=10, ставит D=4, E=2.
И так далее C=35 -> D=5, E=6.

Comment: Можете показать свою логику, как пробовали решать данную задачу. Опишите в самом вопросе более корректно, что не получается. Сложно понять логику

Comment: Я только начал, столкнулся с такой проблемой, думаю как это обыграть. Есть екселевские таблицы, в которых все колонки вводятся вручную, нужно немного автоматизировать. Или как то в екселе мучаться или сделать оболочку и програмно это записать, Есть 3 колонки, которые нужно автоматизировать(остальные знаю как) В первую вводится число от 1 до 36 у этих чисел есть  колонка номер и  колонка порядок их всего 1-6. Тоесть написать в первой колонке число 1, во второй должно проставится 1 и в третьей 1. Вторая и третья колонка известна

Comment: Тоесть к 36 числам как то приделать 2 значения, которые  проставлялись в зависимости от конкретной цифры.